# How to create progress bar like in the following picture?

Tags: qt4, qt4.7

This came from Qt SDK setup wizard , seems that QProgressBar only support accumulative bars , how did they made the following ? is that included in the open-source edition of Qt ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simpler then you think... You just need to `setRange(0, 0)` on QProgressBar. Note that it won't behave exactly like that on all platforms.

With Mac OS X style it will look like this:

[image]

Blue stripes will move to the right

On windows it will look like this (with Vista/7 style):

[image]

Green indicator will appear from left to the right. It will take only part of progress bar of course.

Comment: Could you place a minimal case here , so that i could test ? Only setRange(0,0) doesn't work out ..

Comment: Remember that it will rely on style. Turn on Qt designer and start playing with properties. Change maximum to 0, value will change automaticly to -1. Try using setMaximum and setValue instead, maybe setRange has some "verification" of input arguments. In desinger preview form in different styles

Answer (score 0):

Is blue box enlarge or static ? It can be QProgressBar on top of another control with animation.
If it static, it could just animate Image without any QProgressBar.

Comment: I assume QParallelAnimationGroup will help you to implement this functionality. You need create QWidget with QImage("bluebox.jpg") and then use:    QParallelAnimationGroup *group = new QParallelAnimationGroup;
         QPropertyAnimation *anim = new QPropertyAnimation(image, "pos");
         anim->setDuration(750 + i * 25);
         anim->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InOutBack);
         group->addAnimation(anim);